# validate the form and then post?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

i have a form with few fileds and a submit button... when i click on the submit button the form should validate and throw me an error of missing data but whats happening is that, it post the data and than validate the form

what should i do to validate the form and then post the form?

```
    <body>
     <form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="post" action="">
     <div class="subColumns paragraph">
            <div class="lefty">
                <div class="fontWeight7">  
                    <label for="first_name">
                    First Name:</label>
                    <input id="first_name" class="text required" maxlength="200" 
                        name="first_name"   />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cdc-left">
                <div class="fontWeight7">
                    <label for="last_initial">
                    Last Initial:</label>
                    <input id="last_initial" class="required text" maxlength="200" 
                        name="last_initial"  />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <input id="btnRegister" name="btnRegister" class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit Your Answer" /> 
</form>




 <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#commentForm").validate(); 

        // validate the comment form when it is submitted  
        // validate signup form on keyup and submit
        $("#signupForm").validate({
            rules: {
                firstname: "required",
                lastname: "required",
                username: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },
                password: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5
                },
                confirm_password: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5,
                    equalTo: "#password"
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                topic: {
                    required: "#newsletter:checked",
                    minlength: 2
                },
                agree: "required"
            },
            messages: {
                firstname: "Please enter your firstname",
                lastname: "Please enter your lastname",
                username: {
                    required: "Please enter a username",
                    minlength: "Your username must consist of at least 2 characters"
                },
                password: {
                    required: "Please provide a password",
                    minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
                },
                confirm_password: {
                    required: "Please provide a password",
                    minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long",
                    equalTo: "Please enter the same password as above"
                },
                email: "Please enter a valid email address",
                agree: "Please accept our policy"
            }
        }); 

        $("#commentForm").validate({
            submitHandler: PostData
        });  

    });

    function PostData() {
  debugger
    var _firstName = commentForm.first_name.value;// $('#first_name').value; //first_name.value;
    var _lastName = $('#last_initial').value; //last_initial.value;
    var _city = $('#city').value; //city.value;
    var _state = $('#state').value; //state.value;
    var _country = $('#country').value; //country.value;

     } 

</script>
```

Comment: server side checking although is expensive, but is more reliable ... imagine, user chose to disable javascript?

Comment: @ajreal - I find a great fallacy in your logic, client-side validation doesn't preclude server-side validation, you can (and should, if doing client) do both.

Comment: client side checking is not possible IF without javascript enabled .. or when the javascript is not loaded properly... of course having both checking is ideal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're hooking up the the `click` event on the button, which happens before the `submit` event on the form, instead use the [`submitHandler` callback option](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#Options_for_the_validate.28.29_method) for [`.validate()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options), like this:

```
$("#commentForm").validate({
  submitHandler: PostData
});
```

...and remove this `click` handler completely:

```
$('#btnRegister').click(function () {
  PostData();
});
```

The `submitHandler` only executes when the validation was successful, which would be what you want here.

Comment: @Nick: it did validate the form but never execute the PostData handler and i put break point in the PostData. any idea?

Comment: @Abu - I got the name wrong, it's been a while, make sure you're using `submitHandler` and not `successHandler`, like the updated answer

Comment: @Nick: i have changed to submitHandler but same thing does not execute the PostData

Comment: @Abu - you have a page I can see?

Comment: how you want to see the page? you want me to send you or something?

Comment: @Abu - you have 2 calls to `.validate()`, you need to have just one with the options, so remove your `$("#commentForm").validate();` line

Answer (score 0):

Why not do server-side validation using ASP.NET's validation controls? It has the advantage of being harder to override, as client-side validation can be disabled if the user configures his browser to not run JavaScript.

Comment: @Mathhew: i can not use server side and i am using WCF services on html page.